# How prove exist continous g(x) such f(g(x))=x for $f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3}{3(x^2-1)}$?

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3}{3(x^2-1)}$ for $x\neq {1,-1}$. Prove exist continous g(x) satisfy f(g(x))=x and g(x)>x with every x is belong to R.

$\frac{2g(x)^3-3}{3(g(x)^2-1)}=x$ but how solve? Maybe another way?

Comment: On what domain are you considering $f$?  It's natural domain excludes $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: It's natural domain excludes 1  and −1

Comment: So you wish to find inverses on each of the three domains $(-\infty,-1),(-1,1),(1,\infty)$?

Comment: No, it asks for a single function $g(x)$ on all reals.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the inverse on each of the three domains , but how?

Comment: g(x) on all reals

Comment: Since $f(0)=1,f(-1)=+\infty,f(1)=+\infty$ in the sense of one-sided limits from $(-1,1)$, $f$ cannot be injective when restricted to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: So how do you solve? The original form was: Let $f(x)=\frac{2x^3-3}{3(x^2-1)}$. Prove exist continous g(x) satisfy f(g(x))=x and g(x)>x with every x is belong to R.

Comment: The problem is ill posed. It has no solution.

Comment: Why the problem is ill posed? The second part was: Prove exist a>1 satisfy row $ {a_n}$ n=0,1,2,...
$ a_0 = a, a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ revolve with cycle base is 1995

Comment: $f$ is not injective. Then $f$ has no inverse.

Comment: The second part is ill posed?

Comment: Well, I guess $f$ may have a right-inverse with the required properties (which is what the question actually asks for). Intuition tells me you probably want to invert $f$ in the region $x>1$.

Comment: the first guestion

Comment: @user161825 We only require $f(g(x))=x$ and not $g(f(x))=x$. So $f$ is only required to be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting $f$ one sees that its graph consists of three pieces. In particular $f$ is monotonically increasing on the interval $J:=\ ]1,\infty[\ $, and one has
$$\lim_{x\to1+}f(x)=-\infty,\qquad\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty\ .$$

[image]

Therefore the restriction $f\restriction J$ maps $J$ homeomorphically onto ${\mathbb R}$, and there is a continuous inverse $g:\ {\mathbb R}\to J$. In particular $(f\restriction J)\circ g={\rm id}_{\mathbb R}$, or
$$f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=x\qquad\forall x\in{\mathbb R}\ .$$
The graph of $f\restriction J$ lies completely to the right of the line $y=x$, which implies $g(y)>y$ for all $y\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Thanks, maby show the second part: Prove exist a>1 satisfy row $ {a_n}$ n=0,1,2,...
$ a_0 = a, a_{n+1}= f(a_n)$ revolve with cycle base is 1995

Answer (score -2):

$f(g(x))=x$ so $g(x)$ is inverse of $f(x)$ so nothing but reflection of f(x) on y=x. proceed , you might have to check at $x=1$ though